# What are the typical qualifications of a competitive candidate for a physics theory tenure track position at a mid-ranked R1 institution?

Tags: tenure-track, physics

I currently work in a small 4-year college and wanted to hear from people who have been part of the hiring process for tenure track faculty in mid rank R1 institues in the US.

What makes a candidate competitive these days in terms of (but not limited to ) the following:

1. Publications (both number of publications & citation)
2. Past grants
3. Having or not having previous post docs.
4. Previous Teaching experience
5. Diversity of Publications.
6. Conference Presentations
7. References

Comment: All of the above, of course. But are you asking for concrete numbers? Hiring isn't a matter of adding up points, but assessing candidates' strengths and weaknesses. What specifically are you asking we provide you with?

Comment: Not a concrete number but a sort of average. For example, mostly competitive candidates ususally have this and that. This factor matters more that that. etc.

Comment: This is impossible to answer. Every university has its own standards.

Comment: I think that's a very good question: OP asks for ballpark average for at least a minimal threshold of a "US 50-150 ranked" university. I don't think there's any problem with the question. It is very well defined.

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer in general (other than in general terms) but I can give advice for someone in your position. R1 universities, even mid-range ones are primarily *research* institutions, though they have a varied mission, especially if they are state universities.

But the main questions that will be asked of you and evaluated in your application to such a place is how will you fit into their research program. Some people do that by having some unique practice and experience and others by fitting into an existing research group. You will need to deal with that. Your 1, 2, 6, and 7 are probably the most important sort of factors.

I suspect that your current institution is very different in that regard (though not all are). And, if you can potentially *lead* a research group that will be attractive to doctoral students, all the better.

Comment: His or her present institution might be not ***have*** PhD students in physics (or any other physical science discipline) for he or she to lead a research group.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, most R1 institutions will have such programs. And if they don't, probably want them. I can't actually imagine a mid-range R1 with no solid Physics program at the doctoral level.

Comment: I think the OP wants to *get into* an R1 university and presently teaches at *"a small 4-year college"*.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, yes, that is my understanding. So, whether or not they can lead a program at their current institution isn't the question, nor the intent of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a whole lot on the university, department, and even specific committee.  Here is your list with some things crossed out (almost never relevant) and some added in bold:

1. Publications (both number of publications & citation)
2. Past grants
3. <s>Having or not having previous post docs.</s> **Evidence of creativity and potential in previous research experience.  (Almost without exception, successful candidates have postdoctoral experience.)**
4. <s>Previous Teaching experience</s>
5. <s>Diversity of Publications</s>
6. <s>Conference Presentations</s>**Invited presentations (conferences and colloquia)**
7. References
8. **Alignment with departmental research priorities**
9. **Race and Gender**
10. **Past activity with regard to "diversity, equity, and inclusion"**

Everything in this list is usually somewhat relevant, and sometimes very relevant.  Personally I care almost entirely about 3 and 7.  For recent hires in physics at the University of Arizona it has been mostly 3, 7, 8.